# counting the number of lines in a text file

Tags: c++, file, gcc, text

I'm reading lines off of text file and I'm wondering if this is a good way to go? I had to write the function `numberoflines` to decrease the `number_of_lines variable` by one because within the while loop, for every line it read it adds 2 to the number_of_lines variable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int number_of_lines = 0;

void numberoflines();
int main(){
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("textexample.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while(!myfile.eof()){
            getline(myfile,line);
            cout<< line << endl;
            number_of_lines++;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    numberoflines();

}

void numberoflines(){
    number_of_lines--;
    cout<<"number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines << endl;
}
```

Is there any other easier better way?

Comment: Are you on a UNIX-like system?  If so, are you reading a file with DOS line endings?  If so, one DOS newline may be treated as two UNIX newlines.  (I haven't tested; just a guess.)

Comment: If you're adding 2 per line, shouldn't you divide the result by 2 instead of just reducing it by one?

Comment: Is there a reason you're reinventing the wheel? There are already programs to do this. Try `wc -l`: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?wc

Comment: @casablanca, sorry i meant to say, it adds an extra 1 to the count when it starts off, i suppose i could start the count from -1 in that case. @strager, hmm I was adding newlines before but it didn't work out with getline?. Either way would this method work for linux?.

Comment: My assumption about newlines was wrong.  I was reading your description, and not the code as I should have.  See my answer below for the explanation you're looking for.

Comment: You can use the popen function with the command wc -l as was mentioned earlier and store the output in a variable.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your hack of decrementing the count at the end is exactly that -- a hack.

Far better to write your loop correctly in the first place, so it doesn't count the last line twice.

```
int main() { 
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("textexample.txt");

    while (std::getline(myfile, line))
        ++number_of_lines;
    std::cout << "Number of lines in text file: " << number_of_lines;
    return 0;
}
```

Personally, I think in this case, C-style code is perfectly acceptable:

```
int main() {
    unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
    FILE *infile = fopen("textexample.txt", "r");
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
        if ('\n' == ch)
            ++number_of_lines;
    printf("%u\n", number_of_lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Of course, C++ will also let you do something a bit similar:

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream myfile("textexample.txt");

    // new lines will be skipped unless we stop it from happening:    
    myfile.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws);

    // count the newlines with an algorithm specialized for counting:
    unsigned line_count = std::count(
        std::istream_iterator<char>(myfile),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(), 
        '\n');

    std::cout << "Lines: " << line_count << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the C-style code. I would suggest doing block reads rather than using `fgetc`, since a function call to read every character incurs a rather high overhead.

Comment: @casablanca: oops -- should have been `getc`, which is typically implemented as a macro.

Comment: Note that if there is only one line not following by a carriage return, std::count will return 0 even though the first line could contains something. Is this an expected behaviour in this context?

Comment: @ForceMagic: Depends on how somebody defines a "line", but yes, it's fairly common -- quite a few line counters just look at new-lines; if they don't find any, the count will be zero.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You may want to add fclose(infile) to the c version and the equivilant to the c++ versions.

Comment: @qwerty9967: Files are flushed and closed automatically when you return from `main`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I agree.  I just thought that it would be good to explicitly close them in the examples so that people know how when they incorporate them into longer programs.

Comment: @qwerty9967: At least IMO, they should *normally* be closed just like they are here: automatically when they go out of scope.

Comment: @casablanca: How to do block reads to perform read operation quickly?

Comment: @JerryCoffin So how would you modify this to handle the case where the last line having or not having a new line doesn't change the "line" count?

Comment: @DavidDoria: I'd normally just use the first version in the answer. If I were really concerned with its memory usage, I might write a version that used `std::ignore` instead of `std::getline`.

Comment: @Caperneoignis: Your comment that : "normally check for the file first is best practice" is just plain *wrong*. Attempting to check for existence of the file separately from opening it is open to race conditions, so it should generally be avoided.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I meant as an if statement IE if fileExist then open it and read it, else print an error message. I was trying to not add a bunch of comments, and making the code unsightly. if (exists(fileName)) { *readFile* } else { cerr << "file does not exist" <<endl; exit(-1);  Or some other handling if the file does not exist. Otherwise ifstream will throw an error and exit.

Comment: But in a threaded environment, I can see where the race condition could exist. But isn't that why you would want a condition before attempting to open the file to ensure the file still exist and hasn't been deleted? Before allowing the thread to grab the lock and access the file?

Comment: I take back the last, you can place the myfile.open() in a if statement before trying to accessing the information. If the .open() returns false, you can handle programmitically, like asking for a file string again, or however. You are correct, I should have just said place it in an if condition, to ensure the file is indeed reachable before trying to read from it.

Comment: For cleanup sake, I would recommend to also close the files after you finish counting the lines.

Answer (score 9):

I think your question is, "why am I getting one more line than there is in the file?"

Imagine a file:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

The file may be represented in ASCII like this:

```
line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
```

(Where `\n` is byte `0x10`.)

Now let's see what happens before and after each `getline` call:

```
Before 1: line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream: ^
After 1:  line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:         ^

Before 2: line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:         ^
After 2:  line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:                 ^

Before 2: line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:                 ^
After 2:  line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:                         ^
```

Now, you'd think the stream would mark `eof` to indicate the end of the file, right?  Nope!  This is because `getline` sets `eof` if the end-of-file marker is reached ["during it's operation"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/).  Because `getline` terminates when it reaches `\n`, the end-of-file marker isn't read, and `eof` isn't flagged.  Thus, `myfile.eof()` returns false, and the loop goes through another iteration:

```
Before 3: line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:                         ^
After 3:  line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n
  Stream:                         ^ EOF
```

How do you fix this?  Instead of checking for `eof()`, see if `.peek()` returns `EOF`:

```
while(myfile.peek() != EOF){
    getline ...
```

You can also check the return value of `getline` (implicitly casting to bool):

```
while(getline(myfile,line)){
    cout<< ...
```

Comment: The return value of `getline` resolves to `false` in a bool context when it fails; *i.e.*, it tried to read past the EOF.

Comment: @greyfade, This is correct, but that doesn't change anything I've said.  I did add an example of using that at the end, though.

Answer (score 2):

with for-loop:

```
std::ifstream myFile;
std::string line;
int lines;

myFile.open(path);

for(lines = 0; std::getline(myFile,line); lines++);

std::cout << lines << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C if you implement count line it will never fail.
Yes you can get one extra line if there is stray **"ENTER KEY"** generally at the end of the file.

File might look some thing like this:

```
"hello 1
"Hello 2

"
```

Code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define FILE_NAME "file1.txt"

int main() {

    FILE *fd = NULL;
    int cnt, ch;

    fd = fopen(FILE_NAME,"r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
            perror(FILE_NAME);
            exit(-1);
    }

    while(EOF != (ch = fgetc(fd))) {
    /*
     * int fgetc(FILE *) returns unsigned char cast to int
     * Because it has to return EOF or error also.
     */
            if (ch == '\n')
                    ++cnt;
    }

    printf("cnt line in %s is %d\n", FILE_NAME, cnt);

    fclose(fd);
    return 0;
}
```