# How to count line numbers in a file?

Tags: c++, position, ifstream, line-numbers

I have an open text file, with the cursor at a certain position. I need to find the cursor's line number. Which of the following approaches is the best under a performance point of view?

1) Store the current position in a variable 'pos', and search for all the '\n' characters from the beginning of the file up to 'pos'.

```
ifstream in("file.txt");
// move anywhere in the file
int lineNum = 0;
std::string line;
istream::pos_type pos = in.tellg();
in.seekg(0);
while ( std::getline(in, line) ) {
   ++lineNum;
   if(in.tellg() >= pos) break;
}
```

2) Do the same thing using a separate ifstream.

3) Anything else?

Comment: How are you moving into the current position? It might be the most efficient to simply keep track of the cursor's line at all times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [counting the number of lines in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file)

Comment: `std::getline(in, std::string())` <-- Binding a non-const reference to a temporary is not legal C++, even if your compiler (Visual C++, right?) happens to accept it.

Comment: I'm surprised that this compiles.  As far as I can tell, `istream::pos_type` isn't supposed to support `>=`.  (Under Unix and Windows, you can probably get the same effect by converting both to `streamoff`.  I don't think that this is guaranteed to be truly portable, though.)

Answer (score 1):

From a performance point of view, it might be better to not use streams and simply read the entire file from beginning to the current position to one large string (using e.g. fread) and counting the occurences of the newline delimiter from the resulting string in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The API is a great spot to help

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n ); 
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

Get line Extracts characters from the stream as unformatted input and stores them into s as a c-string, until either the extracted character is the delimiting character, or n characters have been written to s (including the terminating null character).

The delimiting character is the newline character ('\n') for the first form, and delim for the second: when found in the input sequence, it is extracted from the input sequence, but discarded and not written to s.

**So, the best way would be to simply iterate with a while loop and increment your counter. You do not need to search for the newline as the function does it for you.**