# C++ | Counting Lines in a File between two specific points

Tags: c++, string, file, search, counting

I just recently started with c++ and would love to know how to count the lines between to specific points in a file. I can already sucessfully find the first point from which I want to start counting but I don't know how to get any further.

Here is what I got so far :

```
ifstream fin;
string line;

char* search = "Key:";
char* search2 = "Color:";

// Open the file.
fin.open(filename);

// Check if it was successful in opening the file.
if (fin.fail() == true)
{
    return false;
}

// Read from the file and continue to read until the end of the file is reached.
while (getline(fin, line)) {

    if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos) {
        //Start counting line ??
    }
}
```

Would be thankfull for any help.

Comment: Tbh, I am not sure what your problem is. Your comment already shows the clue.

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code, something like:

```
unsigned int count_lines=0;
unsigned int ignore_lines=0;

// Read from the file and continue to read until the end of the file is reached.
while (getline(fin, line)) {
    count_lines++;
    if (line.find(search, 0) != string::npos) {
        ignore_lines = count_lines;
    }
    if (line.find(search2, 0) != string::npos) {
        // The number of rows is count_lines - ignore_lines
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking to complicated instead of using simple counter Variables, but thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need a variable to store the count, then you also need a variable to determine if you are counting currently:

```
int count = 0;
bool counting = false;

while(...) {
  if(...)
    counting = true;

  if(...)
    counting = false;

  if(counting)
    ++count
}
```