# How to count the number of lines of an input file?

Tags: c++

I know that every line of an input file contains five numbers, and I want my c++ program to automatically determine how many lines are in the file without asking the user. Is there a way to do this without using getline or the string class?

Comment: This question's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file top-voted answer presents 2 methodologies that do not use std::string or getline.  One solution is a C-style file reading using  `getc()` and one is a C++ `istream_iterator` solution.

Comment: Why can't you use `getline` or `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it...

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileName = "Data.txt";
    std::ifstream f(fileName, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    int fileSize = f.tellg() / 5 * sizeof(int);

    return 0;
}
```

The code assumes a file named Data.txt and that the 5 numbers on each line are of type int and are not separated by space or delimiters. Keep in mind that in the case of a text file, each line will terminate to a newline so this technique, which does not take them into account, will give misleading results.

Comment: This also assumes each number is only one digit.  I doubt that is how it is.

Comment: @NathanOliver, 'sizeof(int)' assumes one digit?

Comment: Opps didn't see that.  `sizeof(int)` more than likely will evaluate to `4` so this assumes there will be 5, 4 digit numbers

Comment: Yes, I leave it up to Fred to calculate that part. For all I know he could be storing them as double or float.

Comment: The number of bytes used to store an `int` in a file does not have to be `sizeof(int)`

Comment: The only time the number of bytes used to store an int would not be sizeof(int) is if there is space or delimiters between the ints, right?

Comment: `1` is 1 byte, `12` is 2 bytes, `123` is 3 bytes. As the file contains newlines it is probably a text file. In any case mixing `sizeof` and files is usually a bad idea, as you don't know what compiler made the program which wrote the file.

Comment: Thanks, I included that in the comments.

Comment: Where does your code take into account the size of the newline character(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, all you have to do is simply read the file, while checking for the escape sequences. Note, that the `\n` escape sequence is translated to system-specific newline escape sequence when writing and vice versa while reading **in text mode.**

In general, this code snippet might help you.

Given the file **somefile.txt**

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

Compiling the code below and inputing the file name *somefile.txt*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

inline size_t newlineCount (std::istream& stream)
{
    size_t linesCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int extracted = stream.get();
        if (stream.eof()) return linesCount;
        else if (extracted == '\n') ++linesCount;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "File: ";
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::ifstream fileStream;
    fileStream.exceptions(fileStream.goodbit);
    fileStream.open(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
    if (!fileStream.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file \"" << filename << "\". Aborting." << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    std::cout << "Lines in file: " << newlineCount(fileStream) << std::endl;
    fileStream.close();
}
```

Gives the output

```
File: somefile.txt
Lines in file: 4
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @NeilKirk Thanks for your reply. I've updated the answer for a post-check loop.

Comment: `get` returns if it has reached the end of file.

Comment: @NeilKirk Moved the implementation to the `inline size_t newlineCount (std::istream& stream)` for the readability.