# How to report progress without going through the entire file before I process

Tags: qt, qfile

I have to parse a big file with several thousand records. I want to display a progress bar, but I do not know the number of recordings in advance. Do I have to roll over this file twice?

- The first to know the number of recording.
- The second to perform the treatment

Or is there a more simple way to get the number of records without going through the entire file before I process ?

My code snippet :

```
void readFromCSV(const QString &filename){

    int line_count=0;
    QString line;           

    QFile file(filename); 
    if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
        return;

    QTextStream in(&file);

    while(!in.atEnd()){                             //First loop
        line = in.readLine();           
        line_count++;
    }

    while (!in.atEnd()) {                           //Second loop
        ...
        line = in.readLine();
        process();
        ...
    }
}
```

Thank you for help

This question is different from the one here : [counting the number of lines in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file)

1) The loop process is already done. In this case it is prevention of double shooting.

2) The code is a QT one, not a C++ fonction to add as a redundancy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting the number of lines in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file)

Comment: Qt does not handle what you want, and by general recommendation is better to use standard C ++, if you want to count how many lines anyway you have to read the file, there is no other way. The solutions of the other post are optimal compared to your implementation.Qt uses C ++ so C ++ solutions are also Qt solutions

Comment: Where does this file come from? If it's made by your application, you could put the number of records on the first line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no way to count lines without reading the file at least once. To avoid it I wouldn't rely on the number of lines, but rather on how much data I have been read. Here is how I would solve this problem:

```
QFile file(fileName);
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text);

const auto size = file.size();

QTextStream in(&file);
while (!in.atEnd()) {
  auto line = in.readLine();
  // Process line.
  // [..]

  // Calculate the progress in percent.
  auto remains = file.bytesAvailable();
  auto progress = ((size - remains) * 100) / size;
  printf("progress: %d%%\r", progress);
}
```

Comment: Thank you vahancho. It's exactly the way I finished to think is was the right one. Based on the file size and not on the number of lines whereas the structure of lines is the same. It's a really good solution for me, just to keep informed the user of how load has been done in the process.

Comment: @vahancho, perfect and solves a valid question! one comment though :) with respect to code _scale_, which is by itself very small .. I couldn't swallow  calling `file.bytesAvailable()` every iteration .. I was thinking better to call it before the loop, then extract size of each line processed.

Comment: @MohammadKanan, thank's for your comment. WRT your proposal, you will still need to call a function on each iteration. Besides, getting the size of the line is not enough - you need to convert it to bytes before subtraction. I don't think you will gain anything with this approach.

Comment: @vahancho, fine, call function each iteration is must anyway .. but if the file is large enough `bytesAvailable()` might involve disk read each iteration?

Comment: @MohammadKanan, Hm, good point, but if you take a look at implementation of `QIODevice::bytesAvailable()` you will notice that it has a constant time complexity and it looks pretty fast.

Comment: @vahancho, yes, good also point. I wanted to close here ... but just to make it complete  .. _at most t_ does not mean running time does not have to be independent of the _problem size_ , makes me conclude the _disk read_ operation is not necessarily faster than checking size of buffered line.