# Read numbers from a file into a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a .txt file that is formatted as follows:

```
906 25 25
1997 25 25
900 25 25
1990 50 1.75
1981 50 50
925 25 25
```

I have written the following code to read the numbers into an array:

```
float numbers[1029][2];
std::ifstream fin;
fin.open("GiftCardFinal.txt");
if (!fin.is_open())
{
    return 0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 1029; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        fin >> numbers[i][j];
    }
    
}
fin.close();
```

However, when I run this code to test if it read the numbers correctly...

```
std::cout << numbers[0][0] << " ";
std::cout << numbers[0][1] << " ";
std::cout << numbers[0][2] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << numbers[1][0] << " ";
std::cout << numbers[1][1] << " ";
std::cout << numbers[1][2] << " ";
```

It outputs:

```
906 25 25

25 1997 25
```

Can anyone help with this or offer advice on what I can improve?

Comment: Increasing the 2nd dimension to 3 can be a good start.

Comment: `std::cout << numbers[0][2]` goes outside the boundaries of the 2nd array dimension.

Comment: I did originally set it to 3. I changed it to 2 when I didn’t understand why it wasn’t working

Comment: Setting it to 3 results in the following output: 906 25 1997

1997 25 900

Comment: When you set the 2nd dimension to 3, your inner loop is not filling the 2nd dimension. Try `j < 3`

Comment: I have tried j < 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
using namespace std;

#define NUM_LINE 10000

int main()
{
    float numbers[NUM_LINE][3];
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("GiftCardFinal.txt");
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LINE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            fin >> numbers[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    fin.close();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LINE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << numbers[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
906 25 25
1997 25 25
900 25 25
1990 50 1.75
1981 50 50
925 25 25
```

Comment: It has to read ~1000 rows and 3 columns each

Comment: I updated my code. You can change the value of `NUM_LINE` if you already know the number of lines in your input file. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482064/counting-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file) if you do not know the number of lines in the input file beforehand.

Comment: How are the for loops different from the original ones? Thank you for the help

Comment: I moved the point of code change to one line instead of three. Check your `numbers` array declaration and the outer for loops. Right now you need to only change the value of number of lines in `#define NUM_LINE 10000`.

Comment: Okay, your code works for all of the files. Thank you. I am still a little unsure as to why my code did not work properly though

Comment: Your code did not work because you declared the `numbers` array with wrong dimension. It should be `1029 x 3`.